The order of growth of a polynomial
This problem is from Stein's Complex Analysis, Chapter 5, Exercise 2.
My try:
Let $p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$ denote a polynomial.
Then we easily get $|p(z)|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{n}|a_k||z|^k$.
Let $|a_k|=\frac{b_k}{k!}$, and $B = \mathop{max}\limits_{{0}\leq{k}\leq{n}}b_k$.
Then $|p(z)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{b_k}{k!}{|z|^k}}\leq Be^{|z|}$.
So $\rho_p \leq 1$, where $\rho_p$ denotes the order of growth of $p(z)$.
However, I couldn't show that there is no lower boundary of $\rho_p$. As a result, though I guess the answer is 1, I cannot safely conclude it.

What is $\rho_p$ ?

@RyszardSzwarc it is the order of growth of p(z). I'll edit to make it clear, thanks.

It turns out $\rho_p$ is actually $0$.
Notice that:
$$e^{z^{1/m}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k/m}}{k!} \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k}}{(mk)!}$$
for all positive integer $m$.
Then by a similar process in the question, we get:
$$|p(z)| \leq Ae^{|z|^{1/m}}$$
where $m$ is a positive integer.
So $$\rho_p = inf_{m\in{\mathbb{N^*}}}\frac{1}{m} = 0$$
